# Spring Boot vs. Apache CXF for RESTful Web Services?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, cxf

I am part of a coding competition, the task is to create a RESTful online marketplace where users can post buy and sell requests via http.

I need to build a front end web service that accepts and stores these requests.

The tech requirements include both Spring boot and CXF. As far as I am aware, both CXF and Spring boot are capable of accepting http requests.

In spring boot, you use a controller like:

```
@Controller
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class controller {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    String home() {
        return "Hello, World!";
    }
}
```

Whereas with CXF (using javax.ws.rs), the code might look like this:

```
@WebService(serviceName = "MarketService", targetNamespace = "http://localhost:9005")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public interface MarketService {

    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Path("/sells/{id}")
    public prod getProduct(@PathParam("id") int id);
```

Can someone help me understand the fundamental difference between these two approaches to handling http requests? Is there a way I can use both Spring Boot and CXF in the same application?

Comment: the spring sample really isn't spring boot...it looks more like spring-mvc.  You may be using spring-boot to get your app up and running...but the code you're using is spring-mvc stuff.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Spring MVC and Apache CXF are 2 separate frameworks to handle HTTP requests and that can be used to build REST web services.

- *Spring MVC* is a project under the Spring "umbrella" (and therefore strongly tied to the Spring framework on top of which it's built),
- *Apache CXF* is a open-source implementation of JAX-RS (REST) and JAX-WS (SOAP). Apache CXF can be run standalone or be included in a Spring application.

If you are looking to build a REST web service, they are pretty much mutually exclusive (you have to pick one). If all you're going to do is build REST web services, then they're pretty much equivalent. If you also need to have an MVC framework to serve HTML pages, then Spring MVC has that capability (CXF does not).

**Personal opinion**: Spring MVC is easier to get started with (thanks to Spring Boot which handles most of the configuration for you) than CXF (which requires more XML configuration).

PS: in your CXF example, you have a `@WebService` annotation. This annotation is part of JAX-WS (SOAP), not JAX-RS (REST). You probably don't need it.

Comment: just a little comment from a notice here; using REST WS then REST web-services really confused me thinking these must be different things (Maybe they are??). Maybe a little edit to make it more clear.

Comment: I initially understood from this answer that Spring is not suitable for SOAP projects, but it appears that I misunderstood, as exemplified here: https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-soap-webservice-example/ . BTW, the Spring framework is also  open-source.

Answer (score 2):

Use the Spring Boot CXF JAX-RS starter by adding:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
  <artifactId>cxf-spring-boot-starter-jaxrs</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

See also: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/springboot.html

Answer (score 1):

Check this project out for nice starter for JAX-RS (REST) that leverages CXF on Tomcat via TomEE.

Everything is all setup and ready to go.

- https://github.com/tomitribe/tomee-jaxrs-starter-project

Long description here:

- http://www.tomitribe.com/blog/2014/06/apache-tomee-jax-rs-and-arquillian-starter-project

Note, running CXF "Standalone" still requires a Servlet container (Tomcat or Jetty), so the above is several steps completed, simplified and finished in a small starter project.  Designed for impatient people (like myself) that don't like to read directions and just like to start hacking.  Always easier for me to start with something that works and then tweak it.